# Database Project Dropping Permissions On Deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have a SQL 2005 Database Project in VS2010. I have a user who is being created and given permissions to the database.

**Test.user.sql**

```
CREATE USER [$(MachineName)\Test] FOR LOGIN [$(MachineName)\Test] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'$(MachineName)\Test'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'$(MachineName)\Test'
GO
```

I have a SQLCMDVAR defined for `$(MachineName)` which holds the name of the machine depending on the selected configuration (Debug (Dev), QA, UAT, Production). This variable is being set correctly at the top of the generated SQL:

```
:setvar MachineName "TheMachineName"
```

When I deploy this project, the user that is created in the script above is dropped and then recreated and the permissions for the user are revoked. During deployment, what is generated regarding this user and its permissions depends on the state of the user in the database.

If the user exists with the `datareader` and `datawriter` permissions, those permissions are revoked, the user is dropped, then the user is recreated and the permissions are not. Visual studio adds this line where the `sp_addrolemember` commands should be:

```
PRINT N'Altering <unnamed>...';
GO
PRINT N'No script could be generated for operation 2 on object ''<unnamed>''.';
GO
PRINT N'Altering <unnamed>...';
GO
PRINT N'No script could be generated for operation 2 on object ''<unnamed>''.';
GO
```

If I deploy the project again, the permissions are correctly generated and applied to the user:

```
PRINT N'Creating <unnamed>...';
GO
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'$(MachineName)\Test';
GO
PRINT N'Creating <unnamed>...';
GO
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datawriter', @membername = N'$(MachineName)\Test';
GO
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, any suggestions?

Comment: I've just had a similar issue - deploying directly from VS has revoked ALL of my users' permissions.

Comment: @Alex, it's really frustrating. And doesn't look like any has any input!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Visual Studio. See [vsts 2010 database deployment error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/640136/vsts-2010-database-deployment-error) and [vsts 2010 database deployment error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688173/vsts-2010-database-deployment-error). There's some indication that this may be fixed in [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686). You're out of luck with this if you are on XP though as SSDT requires Vista or later to install.

Comment: I've upgraded a number of my DB projects to MSSQL Server Data Tools but haven't yet confirmed if this bug still exists.